# Html Link Changes Color? No Explination

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink, hex

```
<style>
a.a:link,a.a:visited
{
display:block;
width:120px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#ff7100;
background-color:#98bf21;
text-align:center;
padding:4px;
text-decoration:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
</style>

<a class='a' href="">link</a>
```

for some reason when   `color:#ff7100;` gets another `#` when the link is clicked it changed to orange then sends you to the page u linked to but if the extra `#` is not there its just another normal link.. i find this strange because i have never seen this before any one have an explination?

Comment: Why do your `a` elements have a class called `a`?

Comment: That should be `<style>` not `<script>` .

Comment: they have a class called a because i have a nav bar im going a-b with my website each div or any thing that needs css has its own class to it and srry the script thing was a typo

Comment: When it's clicked? So you mean it's an active link ?  There are 4 link CSS properties, :link :active :hover :visited

Comment: yes when it is active it flickers

Comment: lol looking back on this question makes me feel dumb i need to pay more attention to the code i write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be `<style>` not `<script>` .
You should not use empty `href` tags, the usual is to use `#` instead (empty hashtag).

That may be because when you click on a lick it actually goes in its `active` state, so you also have to define `css` for `a:active`

Try this selector instead:

```
a.a:link,a.a:visited,a.a:active,a.a:hover
```

Comment: i fixed the typos and the links on my actual page are not empty but this is still annoying me because the link flashes when its clicked if it has an extra #

Comment: Create an example on www.jsfiddle.net which reproduces that error.

Comment: ok here it is http://jsfiddle.net/VvRQX/ i looked under google chrome and it dosent flicker it flickers on safari.. i dont know why

Comment: You have an extra '#' after color, remove it.

Comment: yes i know that thats what i mean with an extra # the link flashes without it it dosent i wanted to find out why .

Comment: Well that's more of a stupid question to be honest. Why would you add another `#` ? In CSS hex colors start with a `#` and only one, followed by 3 or 6 digits or leters up to `F`.

Comment: i know why it was doing it my Cpanel was being worked on they just emailed us not to use it for 24 hrs while they fix it all css colors got an extra # i will have to fix it